# MySQL GROUP CONCAT duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table of results that looks like this:

```
score_id, uid, af_id, level, record_date
```

Where `uid` is the user id of a user on the system. `af_id` is a focus which a level has been set at.  An `af_id` will be either 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.  `Level` is an integer value, ranging from 3 - 7.

A sample data set would be:

```
1, 2, 1.1, 4, 2012-09-02
2, 2, 1.2, 4, 2012-09-02
3, 2, 1.3, 3, 2012-09-02
4, 2, 1.3, 4, 2012-11-30
```

I need to query the database to collect what level a user has reached for each `af_id` between certain dates.  I am using `GROUP_CONCAT` to bring the data into one row.  My query works for the first period of time, but produces duplicates there after.  My SQL so far is:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.forename, u.surname, ui.gender, GROUP_CONCAT(us.level ORDER BY us.af_id SEPARATOR ',') AS levels
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_scores us
ON us.uid=u.uid AND us.record_date > '2012-09-01' AND us.record_date < '2012-10-20'
JOIN user_info ui ON ui.uid =u.uid
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY u.surname ASC
```

This gives the result:

```
Joe Bloggs  M  4,4,3
```

I want to be able to widen the months so that my query will be able to return updated results for af_id's.  So if I widen the results dates to range between 2012-09-01 and 2012-12-31.  I would like to see the following results:

```
Joe Bloggs  M  4,4,4
```

However, my query (using the above SQL) returns the following result:

```
Joe Bloggs  M  4,4,3,4
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised query.  You state that it should be able to retrieve historic, and sounds like you are just interested in the highest level attained.  To this end the inner query just needs to limit the max date on user_scores, and can simply retrieve uid, af_id, and the MAX(level).

This can then be joined onto `users u`, and in turn GROUP_CONCAT can return you the focuses and their relevant max scores.  If an additional focus is added later then it will be returned.

This will not return focus 1.2 if a user has no scores in focus 1.2

```
SELECT 
    u.uid, 
    u.forename, 
    u.surname, 
    ui.gender,
    GROUP_CONCAT(us.af_id) AS focusOrder,
    GROUP_CONCAT(us.level ORDER BY us.af_id ASC) AS focusMaxLevels
FROM users u

INNER JOIN user_info ui 
    ON ui.uid =u.uid

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        uid,
        af_id,
        MAX(level) as level
    FROM user_scores
    WHERE record_date <= DATE('2012-10-20')
    GROUP BY uid, af_id
    ORDER BY uid ASC, af_id ASC 
) AS us
ON us.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY u.surname ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not provide the result I am looking for. I need to have a result for each af_id. Using DISTINCT only returns two results:

Joe Bloggs  M  4,3

The desired result for the months between September and December woudl be:

Joe Bloggs  M  4,4,4

Comment: Hi Simon the data is to be queried and placed in a tabbed web interface. Each tab will represent a period of time eg Sept - Oct, Nov - Dec.  The data will display a table of results and show a progress. So for example in Sept - Oct the results for AF 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 would be 4, 4, 3. However, in Nov - Dec the data would show say 4,4,4. Over the course of a year these numbers would change as higher levels are achieved, but only 3 results should be shown for each time period.  If new scores are not achieved for each AF then the levels from the previous time period are used. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The above should help further - have revised based on new information.

Comment: Hi Simon that's great.  It works.  Much appreciated :)  I have added a slight amendment to the GROUP_CONCAT order to have the results in ascending order of af_id.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The inner join would have been ordered by uid ASC, afid ASC.  If you reorder the GROUP_CONCAT in the outer query they won't necessarily match each section specifically, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Timeline: your 3rd revision completely wrong, then my answer, your 4th revision correcting answer (still details wrong), OP suggests edit to your answer to correct details (rejected later), OP accepts, your last edit basically identical to suggested by OP except for ORDER BY inside subselect which changes nothing.

Comment: @piotrm - I have stated already to you that I copied nothing from you.  This is the solution that I reached following clarification with OP.  These additional comments help nothing and are not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you get your results for each af_id by pure coincidence - there is exactly one row matching your set date range for each af_id in your example data. You need to group by uid,af_id first to get level, I'm guessing here you need the highest one, so MAX() would by suitable.

```
SELECT u.uid, u.forename, u.surname, ui.gender, GROUP_CONCAT(us.level ORDER BY us.af_id ) AS levels
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( SELECT  uid, af_id, MAX(level) as level
  FROM user_scores 
  WHERE record_date > '2012-09-01' AND record_date < '2012-12-31'
  GROUP BY uid, af_id ) us
ON us.uid=u.uid
JOIN user_info ui ON ui.uid =u.uid
GROUP BY u.uid
ORDER BY u.surname ASC
```